# $2\mathbb{Z}\cong 3\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules

> Why is $2\mathbb{Z}\cong 3\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?

I gave the following homomorphism:

$f:2\mathbb{Z}\to 3\mathbb{Z}$, $n\mapsto \frac32n$

Since $n\in 2\mathbb{Z}$ this function is well-defined, because $n=2m$ and $\frac{3}{2}n\in 3\mathbb{Z}$

f is a homomorphism of abelian groups, since

$f(a+b)=\frac32(a+b)=\frac32a+\frac32b=f(a)+f(b)$ and for every $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ it is

$f(za)=\frac32za=z\cdot\frac32a=zf(a)$,

hence f is a $\mathbb{Z}$-homomorphism.

Also it is a bijection with the obvious inverse function $f^{-1}: 3\mathbb{Z}\to 2\mathbb{Z}$, $m\mapsto \frac23m$

> Question: Can we define $f$ like this? Since it uses a operation which is not necessarly well-defined on $\mathbb{Z}$, since $\frac32\in\mathbb{Q}$, or does this simply not matter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The operation is not well-defined on $\Bbb Z$, but it is well-defined as a map from $2\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$. Just because you use fractional notation to tell us what the map is doesn't mean it doesn't work.

Comment: To be a bit more specific: using fractional notation doesn't mean it doesn't work. It _does_ mean, however, that it doesn't _automatically_ work, so you have to justify it. But that is exactly what you did, so it's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly good, since it is well defined as a map from $2 \mathbb Z \to \mathbb 3 \mathbb Z$.

If it makes you more comfortable, you could remark that as a $\mathbb Z$ module, it is enough to specify maps of generators and take $2 \mathbb Z \to 3\mathbb Z$ by $2  \mapsto 3$, which extends uniquely to a $\mathbb Z$-linear homomorphism since both modules are free on one generator, and moreover it is exactly your map.

---

In light of Ennar's comment, I will include following observation for posterity:

the homomorphism is uniquely determined since $f(2n)=nf(2)=3 \cdot n$ by $\mathbb Z$ linearity.

Comment: It is nice that you point out that the map in the question is $2\mapsto 3$, but if we are going to invoke "freeness", $2\mathbb Z\cong 3\mathbb Z$ is automatic.

Comment: @Ennar you are correct, perhaps there is a nicer way to say the same thing.

Comment: You could just write $f(2n) = nf(2) = 3n$ by $\mathbb Z$-linearity.

Comment: Nice detail to add. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think of the map $n\mapsto \frac 32 n$ is as composition $2\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\to 3\mathbb Z$ where the first map is the inverse of the map $n\mapsto 2n\colon\mathbb Z\to 2\mathbb Z$.

You shouldn't be worried about fractional notation since it is perfectly reasonable to denote the inverse of $n\mapsto 2n$ by $n\mapsto \frac 12 n$. The notation fails if and only if $n\mapsto 2n$ isn't invertible.

Comment: Thanks. I like this too.